# What is the purpose of prepending the folder name to container name in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have my docker compose file in /documents folder and when I use docker-compose up, it appends the folder name to the service name (myappv1).

```
documents_myappv1_1
```

What is the purpose of this?
Why can't it be just `myappv1_1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker Compose uses **project name** to let users deploy [multiple isolated environments on a single host](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host). Project name will use the name of the folder containing your `docker-compose.yml` by default.

You can change the container naming behavior by:

- Using `-p` option such as `docker-compose -p project_name up` which will cause containers to be named like `project_name_myappv1_1`
- Use [`container_name`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#container_name) option to specify a custom container name which will remain the same even on different deployments

---

As [per doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host):

> Compose uses a project name to isolate environments from each other.
> You can make use of this project name in several different contexts:
>
> - on a dev host, to create multiple copies of a single environment, such as when you want to run a stable copy for each feature branch of a project
> - on a CI server, to keep builds from interfering with each other, you can set the project name to a unique build number
> - on a shared host or dev host, to prevent different projects, which may use the same service names, from interfering with each other
>
> **The default project name is the basename of the project directory.** You can set a custom project name by using the `-p` command line option or the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.

Comment: Specifying a distinct `container_name` still seems to conflict with the same project name/service name combination of another `docker-compose.yml`. Note that the mentioned docs do not mention the container_name option you describe.

Comment: Ah thanks, the link did work before but was probably out of date. Updated it. For your other issue, yes if different `docker-compose.yml` specifies the _same_ `container_name`, they will conflict. `container_name` should be unique across projects to ensure uniqueness to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Even if I specify a different `container_name`, `docker-compose up -d` overwrite/recreates the container of another `docker-compose.yml` (with the same project name/service name combination, manually specified `container_name` is different). So, using the `-p` option (or the corresponding environment variable) seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Exactly, different `container_name` defined in `docker-compose.yml` still shuts down the previous container(s) created with the same file but different `container_name`. Another tested option is to copy the `docker-compose.yml` to another (parallel) directory and run `docker compose` with new `container_name`(s) from there - then the previously started container(s) with different `container_name`(s) will stay running. /Docker Compose version v2.24.6 -Docker Buildx v0.12.1

Answer (score 2):

Docker Compose uses the default naming scheme `<project>_<service>_<index>`
to isolate environments, so you can run multiple instances of the same compose-file on one host.
It is explained in the [Docker Compose Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host).

But you can override the container name, as explained also in the [Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name)

```
container_name: my-web-container
```

Comment: Specifying a distinct `container_name` still seems to conflict with the same project name/service name combination of another `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: The purpose of the question was the explanation of the docker-compose naming scheme and a workaround for renaming a service (which my answer doesn't do either, as I now read it again). So the answer to your problem is the `-p` option as @pierreb. answered correctly.